# Python 2.7: Back to utf-8 after using decode unicode-escape

Tags: python, encoding

I am trying to remove chars, but have different inputs (can be `u'ä'` or `\\u0001` and so on) so I used encode(`utf-8`).decode(`unicode-escape`) to bring it to the same format and clean:

```
s = "\\u0001" 
s.encode("utf-8")
'\\u0001'
s.encode("utf-8").decode("unicode-escape")
u'\x01'
```

or

```
s = u'ä'
s.encode("utf-8")
'\xc3\xa4'
s.encode("utf-8").decode("unicode-escape")
u'\xc3\xa4'
```

The question is how to get back to `utf-8` after?
Found `.encode("raw_unicode_escape")` which passes basic tests, but still not sure.

Comment: As mhawke's answer shows, you need to reverse the order of your operations. First decode the byte string containing Unicode escape sequences, then encode the resulting Unicode to a UTF-8 byte string.

Comment: I'm still not _exactly_ sure what your problem is, but hopefully my answer is helpful. :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't understand why (or how) you have a mixture of byte strings and Unicode strings like that. But if that's what you're data is like then you need to process the two types of strings differently.

The code below first prints the representation of each string in `data`, and the type of object that the string is.
It then calls the `decode('unicode-escape')` method on the plain byte strings, which will convert them to Unicode strings.
Then all strings are encoded from Unicode to UTF-8 byte strings.

```
data = [
    'byte string',
    u'unicode string',
    'this byte string has unicode escapes: \\u2122\\u00e6',
    u'this unicode string has non-ascii chars: ©æ™ä',
]

for s in data:
    print repr(s), type(s)
    if isinstance(s, str):
        s = s.decode('unicode-escape')
    z = s.encode('utf8')
    print repr(z), z
    print
```

**output**

```
'byte string' <type 'str'>
'byte string' byte string

u'unicode string' <type 'unicode'>
'unicode string' unicode string

'this byte string has unicode escapes: \\u2122\\u00e6' <type 'str'>
'this byte string has unicode escapes: \xe2\x84\xa2\xc3\xa6' this byte string has unicode escapes: ™æ

u'this unicode string has non-ascii chars: \xa9\xe6\u2122\xe4' <type 'unicode'>
'this unicode string has non-ascii chars: \xc2\xa9\xc3\xa6\xe2\x84\xa2\xc3\xa4' this unicode string has non-ascii chars: ©æ™ä
```

The above output was produced in a terminal that's configured to use UTF-8.

Comment: Thank you! That seems exactly like what I need to do. Will try.

Answer (score 1):

Like this:

```
>>> s = "\\u0001"
>>> s.decode('unicode-escape')
u'\x01'
>>> s.decode('unicode-escape').encode('utf8')
'\x01'
```

Here is an example for which it is a bit more obvious that the result is UTF-8 encoded:

```
>>> s = "\\u3030"
>>> s.decode('unicode-escape')
u'\u3030'
>>> s.decode('unicode-escape').encode('utf8')
'\xe3\x80\xb0'
```

Comment: Thanks for answer, but this one doesn't work for me. I can have an input like `u'ä'`, then I will have an exception trying to decode unicode-escape before converting to "utf-8":
`UnicodeEncodeError: 'ascii' codec can't encode character u'\xe4' in position 0: ordinal not in range(128)`

Comment: @Valentina: In your question, the input data is a byte string, not a Unicode string with the `u` prefix. You should edit your question so we know what your real data looks like.

Comment: @PM 2Ring my fault, sorry. Edited the post